# PHP Headers confusion

Tags: php, header, fclose

I've been banging my head against this one all day long. Time to ask for some help.

So, I have a PHP script, which is a downloads page. Users have files they can download according to what they have ordered.

It goes something like this (not real code obviously, well some bits are - hopefully you can get the gist)

```
PAGE START
if(post[getorder]){

check order exists, get order filename etc from mysql;
update download attempts in db;

$ctype="application/force-download";
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
while ( $contents = fread( $handle, 1024 ) )
{
print (  $contents );
flush();
}
fclose($handle);    
$successmessage = "Your download has begun";                  
}

if($successmessage){
 echo $successmessage;
}

get users order details from db;
display div
 display form with post to post order number to script; 
 end form
end div
END PAGE
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I can put all the code if that would be more useful, but it's a long old script and I thought this might be more convenient.

So, if a user is just viewing the page, the script grabs the user's order information on any orders they might have. Users only get X attempts to download before the order is flagged complete and no longer available.

It displays a div per available order, and inside each div is a small form. If they click on the form, it posts the order number back to the same script at which point I'd hoped it would simply serve the file then continue displaying the rest of the page. Alas no, apparently the headers on the force download grab control and nothing happens after the fclose.

So I thought bugger it, and added a variable into the "if(post...)" along the lines of $sendfile = 1, and right at the bottom of the page...

if($sendfile == 1){ do headers stuff}

...hoping that the page would load up correctly before sending the file and everyone happy. Again, alas no. It serves the file first, and doesn't reload the page.

Again, hopefully my verbiage makes some sense.

I've read that a php script will 'do' the headers first, so doesn't matter where you put them. I don't know if that is true, but based upon what I am seeing, it is.

I've also tried using headers after the fclose to redirect to the same page, and use a simple GET to make the script display the success message. However if I do this, the reload works, but the download prompt does not display. Even if I put a sleep(10) before the redirect to self. It just waits and then reloads, but no file download.

The page re-load is quite important, because when the rest of the page re-gets the order data and displays it, the download attempts should be increased by 1.

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do? The code I am cutting is getting increasingly more hacky so any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, or what the issue at hand is, but your code looks suspicious in general. You try to produce the download and a success message that goes along with the download within the download data. If you want to have a success message and a download, you need to produce them through separate requests, e.g. by producing a page with the "download begun" message first, with the page automatically redirecting to the download that can then be saved, or offering the download through an iframe or through some other means.

Comment: Hi Achimedix, yes I am beginning to see what u mean. I've already had all manner of "appending the page itself to the beginning or end of the download file" - is it the case that you can either send a page, or send a file, but not both? Its a matter of my understanding, I just don't see why you can't load the page first, then do the "sending file" part of the script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the download landing page, try adding `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=/download/file/url">` instead of using headers. This will make the browser load the page, then after 1 second redirect to the file download.

Additionally, if you are serving anything other than small files, I'd recommend that you check out [X-Sendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/).

Comment: Hi Znarkus thanks for your input - files will vary from around 40mb to 300mb - would that warrante X-Sendfile? I looked at the XSendfile page, and it looks like this is also done within headers, so am I not going to hit the same problem again?

Comment: Hi Znarkus, I think I see what you (and Archimedix) are getting at - I guess based on what other sites do, how about if I redirected the user to a "your file is downloading" page, and serve the file from that page? That should work and get around the probs I'm having shouldn't it?

Comment: That is what I proposed :) My "download landing page" is what you describe as "your file is downloading" page. I think X-Sendfile is easier on the server, so it might be worth trying. Not to solve this problem, but to be "future proof". Just make sure to compile  the latest from source.

Comment: Hi Znarkus - thanks I will look at putting XSendfile in when we get our new server. Thanks for the pointer about the refresh, I did end up doing it that way, but would have been quite stuck if I had not had that one bit of info - so thanks for your help.